# Error starting Android emulator via ssh ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, 64-bit

I got the following error when running Android emulator in Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit:

ERROR: Could not create SDL2 window: Couldn't find matching GLX visual

I was able to run the emulator before but looked like there were some damages to my X11 configurations and now I could not run it.

Thanks
Binh

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me after that.:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11
```

Why it works:

An error message that has puzzled many an X user is "Couldn't find matching GLX visual" (or similar) — it means that the program tried to use a GLX visual that was not available on that X server. A possible solution is to change the color depth to something that supports the requested capabilities.

Reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX_visual 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/sdl-couldnt-find-matching-glx-visual